# javascript: How would you make text spin using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif" id="imgid">
<h1 id='header'>Example</h1>
<!--This is an example html doc not the real thing!-->
<button onclick="spin(document.getElementById('header'));spin(document.getElementById('imgid'));">Spin!</button>
<script>
  function spin(object) {
    setInterval(function() {
      object.style.transform += "rotate(10deg)";
    }, 1);
  }
</script>
```

How do I make the text spin correctly? If you could explain how it works then that would be great. If you need any references of my sources then:

- [`SetInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
- [`style.transform`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp)

By "correctly" I mean spinning centered. (Not all over the page).

Thanks!

Comment: What does "spin correctly" mean? It sure is spinning

Comment: You will probably have to resize the text element and change its `transform-origin` property.

Comment: I clarified spinning correctly definition after the references

Comment: I laughed so hard when I clicked the button -- I don't know how you want the end effect to be. Do you want it to spin once and then stop? Or spin forever like it is? Do you want it slower, or faster?

Comment: I can easily make it stop (I'm going to slow it down as you hit it again (the button that is (way to many brackets (I should stop))))

Comment: Why is this "unclear"? I made it quite clear...

Comment: Yeah I don't really understand why this was put on hold four hours after the op marked my answer as correct; everything was really clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The main problem was that the width extended all the way across the page which messed up the rotation, so adding in display:inline-block made the width match up with the div's contents.

```
<style>
#imgid{display:inline-block;}
#myDIV{display:inline-block;}
</style>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif" id="imgid"></div>
        <div><h1 id='myDIV'>Example</h1></div>
        <div><button onclick="spin(document.getElementById('imgid'));spin(document.getElementById('myDIV'));">xdfdsf</button></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
function spin(object)
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        object.style.transform += "rotate(10deg)";
    }, 1);
}
</script>
```